# memory saving gradients or memory check pointing in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I recently found a github repo: https://github.com/openai/gradient-checkpointing
The main purpose is to reduce gpu memory consumption. And the usage seems pretty straight forward:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import backend as K
K.__dict__["gradients"] = memory_saving_gradients.gradients_memory
```

How can I do the same thing but with keras installed separately, not as a part of tensorflow? Since this didn't work:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.__dict__["gradients"] = memory_saving_gradients.gradients_memory
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a bit late, but I recently ran into the same problem, and I was able to solve it.

The problem (I think) is that `memory_saving_gradients.gradients_memory` uses a heuristic approach which does not work well for many scenarios. Fortunately, there is an alternative function: `memory_saving_gradients.gradients_collection`, which works perfectly fine, but it requires you to specify at which points in the network the gradient must be checkpointed.

As an example on how this can be accomplished, suppose that we want to checkpoint all the Keras layers whose name contains the word 'add' (for instance, to make a resnet memory effcient). Then, you could include something like this after building your model, but before training it:

```
layer_names= [layer.name for layer in self.model.layers]
[tf.add_to_collection("checkpoints", self.model.get_layer(l).get_output_at(0)) 
        for l in [i for i in layer_names if 'add' in i]]
K.__dict__["gradients"] = memory_saving_gradients.gradients_collection
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This approach does not work. I've tried it and I do not get any memory savings. Can you please let me know how you got this to work and if you noticed memory usage going down when using it?

Comment: @A.Hendry Hi, I came from future 2028, did you solve this problem? You might save us on 2028.

Comment: @VimNing ...huh?